# Reports get overwrite in case each feature file is having indivisual runners

Tags: selenium, testng, cucumber-java

I am using cucumber with testng. I have created runner files for each feature

1.LoginRunner.java

2.ChangePasswordRunner.java

I am trying to generate rerun.txt for failed case run and
thread timeline report for parallel execution but there comes overwrite results.
How to overcome that?

my runner file code is like

```
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/java/features/ChangePassword.feature"}, monochrome = false,
    plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json", "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty",
            "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
            "rerun:target/rerun/change-password_failed.txt","timeline:target/thread-timeline","steps.StepDetails"},
    glue = {"steps"})
public class ChangePasswordRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
```

}

Comment: Expecting some answers!

Comment: I overcome rerun.txt problem. but there is no clue about thread timeline html report